Shopware 6 - 6.6.2.0
My Shop is running on the latest version of Shopware 6.6 and there are a few pages (for example Settings > Shopware Account ) which show this error Message.
Encountered an error while loading the configuration:Parameter "domain" is missing.
Any Idea how i could solve this ?
My Idea was to downgrade to 6.5 but this doesnt work well.
Showing the Page with the Form
I also take a look add the log File and found this:
[2024-05-29T15:18:03.636531+00:00] request.NOTICE: Uncaught PHP Exception Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\RoutingException: "Parameter "domain" is missing." at RoutingException.php line 30 {"exception":"[object] (Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\RoutingException(code: 0): Parameter "domain" is missing. at /var/www/shopware/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Routing/RoutingException.php:30)"} []

6.6.9999999.9999999 Developer Version is my Current Version
